# Do particles keep on emitting energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, reference-frames

Accelerated electrons emit electromagnetic waves, but those at rest do not. So accelerated electrons emit energy and those at rest do not. (At rest hypothetically, I know it is not permissible according to uncertainity principle)

But lets assume that we keep an electron at rest and start accelerating ourselves pretty fast, now even though we do not move the electron, it seems to move and produce EM waves, we should get these waves, and if we do get these waves then the electron must have released these waves or energy.

However someone standing near the electron should not see these and hence must not say that electron is emitting energy.

Why are the two observations differing  ? Although energy is not conserved across frames, what else can be the source of light in one frame other than the electron which seems to move.

If my thought experiment that electron does emit energy is correct, then why doesnt the standing observer see it ? And even if he does see it in some other form, does this imply that particles continuously lose energy ?

Comment: In your first paragraph, do you mean *accelerated* or *accelerating* electrons? There is a *big* difference between the two.

Comment: Pay attention to the postulates of special relativity here. You can only assume that the laws of physics apply to your observations if *you are in an inertial frame*.

Comment: @dmckee : do you mean to say that laws of physics are not valid in non-inertial frame ? I have never heard so. I assume that I am misunderstanding your comment, so please explain.

Comment: The laws of physics as they are usually written down (like *"accelerating charges radiate"*) only apply in inertial frames. There are mathematical prescriptions that allow you to produce the laws that apply in non-inertial frames, but they do not always have the same form and content as the ones we usually talk about (i.e. a rotating frame has centrifugal and coriolis pseudo-forces). You are trying to apply the untransformed laws to a non-inertia frame. That's an error. It's not valid to compute the electron's acceleration based on it's distance from you without subtracting your acceleration.

Comment: @dmckee : That is very helpful. So, is the law "accelerating charges produce em waves" valid for non-inertial frames, the acceleration being with respect to the observer present in said frame ? If not, does electrons or charges which seem to accelerate in frames do not produce em waves ? Does it also mean that if we see an accelerated electron from its frame we would not see any em waves ?

Comment: Opposite of acceleration isn't rest...

Comment: @sachinshekhar : I don't see anybody saying so ! What's your point ?

Comment: I said so coz you can simply use uniform speed (rest is also uniform speed). BTW, See this: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath528/kmath528.htm It addresses your issue.

Comment: @sachinshekhar : I struggled through the entire paper/article only to realise that according to it no one is sure about what should and does happen ! As said in the very last line "As a result, the Lorentz-Dirac equation does not provide a definite answer to the question of whether a uniformly accelerated charge radiates."

Comment: @dmckee : Just thinking we have always been in a non-inertial frame, and when we see accelerated charge atleast with respect to us, we get em waves that is precisely how radios work, ofcourse it is speculation but it should be valid to get same results by keeping charge here and accelerating ourselves, if relative acceleration is all that is required !

Comment: And, that's the answer... Simply, drop the classical physics and move on.

Comment: @sachinshekhar : The paper you provided involved GR, classical physics is supposedly newtonian. And how is that the answer ?

Comment: The question of whether accelerating electron emit EM wave or not is a classical question. In modern theories, acceleration of electron can't be defined. In QFT, an electron is an excitation in matter field.

Comment: @rijul gupta: It's not very nice of you to ask a yes or no question in this regard, as each answer would entail more inconvenient questions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on radiating EM waves first and forget about energy. When you jump into accelerating train and see charge accelerate away from you, this is all in a non-inertial frame. In this frame, electromagnetic theory has to be formulated with modified equations and new appropriate boundary conditions. That being said, nothing forbids static field in inertial frame to have time-dependent and wave-like component in non-inertial frame.

With energy it is similar. Whether energy is propagating through the field or not may in general depend on which frame is used to describe it; energy is frame-dependent quantity. Conservation of energy will be satisfied in all frames, even in non-inertial frame, because total energy can be defined in such a way that increase in the energy of the particle and the field will be compensated by decrease of potential energy of the system in the field of acceleration force (pseudo-gravity).

Comment: This does not answer the question (does it actually emit EM?).

Comment: If it did emit a photon (EM), it would accelerate in the opposite direction. This is an effect visible to all observers. So, no, one accelerating observer cannot make an electron at rest emit a photon.